# Open a Windows shortcut file `.lnk` with subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, lnk

I am fairly new to Python and have been trying to make a program that will open the "Minecraft launcher" for me.

#### Context

However, the new launcher `.exe` file is blocked as it is located in the windowsapp file which requires a lot of faffing about that I would rather avoid, so instead I was hoping to see if I could open the desktop shortcut instead to open the launcher directly?

#### Error

This code so far doesn't work as it gives me the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

#### Code

```
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('C:/Users/(my username)/Desktop/Minecraft Launcher.lnk')
```

I have tried `subprocess.call` however that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.lnk` files are interpreted by the shell. So, enable the shell:

```
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\My Username\\Desktop\\Minecraft Launcher.lnk", shell=True)
```

As a side note, the shell is one of the very few things in Windows that insists on backslashes.